# Array of Objects add amount for id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My question is how can I proper add values of an a array of object by id a create other array for example, I have:

```
var array = [{"key":"1","amount":200},{"key":"2","amount":200},{"key":"1","amount":200}];

var resultArray=[{"key":"1","amount":400},{"key":"2","amount":200}]
```

Comment: And my question is what have you tried so far?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: you can do it using javascript in many ways. depending on your needs you pick one. (Or you may consider using some of the libraries that provide common operations, such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/))